# Ошибка при записи в csv файл Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, кодировка, csv

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS 
import csv


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok:
        return r.text
    else:
        print(r.status_code)


def write_csv(data):
    with open('4,1.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((data['group'], 
                        data['name'],
                        data['date'],
                        data['time'],
                        data['url']))



def fixing_date(text, number):
    text = text.split(' ')
    date = text[0]
    time = text[1]

    if number == 0:
        return date
    elif number == 1:
        return time


def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

    articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='simple-post')
    
    for article in articles:
        
        try:
            group = article.find('p', class_='simple-share').find('a').text
        except:
            group = ''

        try:
            name = article.find('h3').find('a').text
        except:
            name = ''

        try:
            dates = article.find('p', class_='simple-share').find_all('span')[0].text.strip()
            
            date = fixing_date(dates, 0)
            time = fixing_date(dates, 1)

        except:
            dates = ''

        try:
            url = 'http://kabar.kg' + article.find('h3').find('a').get('href')
        except:
            url = ''


        data = {'group': group,
                'name': name,
                'date': date,
                'time': time,
                'url': url}

#       print(data)

        write_csv(data)
        


def main():
    urls = 'http://kabar.kg/cat/strategiia-2040/page{}'

    for i in range(1, 9):
        url = urls.format(str(i))

        get_page_data(get_html(url))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Это парсер, и он работает. Если выводить, например, словарь `data` в консоль, то он выводит все нужные данные, но если я начинаю записывать это все в `csv` файл, то выходит ошибка **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u04a3' in position 52: character maps to undefined**.
Никогда не сталкивался с такой ошибкой, что еще за символ `\u04a3`, откуда он взялся я не знаю, но из-за этого возникает ошибка (как я понял в кодировке). Помогите разобраться и исправить, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых я не уверен, что запятая в названии файла - это хорошо. Кажется, не всякая операционная система переварит нормально файл с таким названием:

> `4,1.csv`

Во-вторых на линуксе в Google Colab ваш код работает без проблем. Думаю, у вас Windows и файл записывается в кодировке, в которой нет каких-то символов, которые вы пытаетесь записать. Попробуйте явно указать кодировку, например:

```
with open('4_1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Хотя `Python 3` вроде бы по умолчанию всё должен делать в `UTF-8`, вероятно придётся ещё поразбираться.

Comment: даа, запись encoding='utf-8'помогла